# Get content of web page field to Javascript variable [Firefox Addon-SDK]

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon, mozilla, firefox-addon-sdk

I am using Firefox Addon SDK to develop Firefox Mozilla add-on/extension.
Now I would like to get field value "user" from displayed web site, when the user clicks on my Add-on button.Web page's form looks like this:

```
<form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
   Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="name of the user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

So I need to display the value "name of the user" in my Add-on textbox, which I had created inside of the Add-on.

But I can't figured out how to pass data FROM THE WEBSITE to the ADDON VARIABLE/SITE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this using a content script. Assuming you have html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form><input type="text" id="txt-field" value="this is the value"/></form>
</body>
</html>
```

...what you need to do is use the page-mod module to attach a content script to the page that can then fetch the value and send it back.

main.js:

```
const data = require('self').data;

var currentVal = false;

require('page-mod').PageMod({
  include: 'https://some.url/index.html',
  contentScriptFile: data.url('script.js'),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.on('val', function(data) {
      currentVal = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
});
```

script.js:

```
self.port.on('fetch-value', function() {
  self.port.emit('val', document.querySelector('#txt-field').value);
});
```

This is a very simple example just to show you how communication from main.js and a content script can work. For more, I highly recommend you read the documentation on content scripts:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts